# Merge dataframes based on column, only keeping first match

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes like the following.

```
df_1    
Index   Fruit
1       Apple
2       Banana
3       Peach

df_2    
Fruit   Taste
Apple   Tasty
Banana  Tasty
Banana  Rotten
Peach   Rotten
Peach   Tasty
Peach   Tasty
```

I want to merge the two dataframes based on `Fruit` but only keeping the first occurrence of `Apple`, `Banana`, and `Peach` in the second dataframe. The final result should be:

```
df_output       
Index   Fruit   Taste
1   Apple   Tasty
2   Banana  Tasty
3   Peach   Rotten
```

Where `Fruit`, `Index`, and `Taste` are column headers. I tried something like `df1.merge(df2,how='left',on='Fruit` but it created extra rows based on the length of `df_2`

Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) for first rows:

```
df = df_1.merge(df_2.drop_duplicates('Fruit'),how='left',on='Fruit')
print (df)
   Index   Fruit   Taste
0      1   Apple   Tasty
1      2  Banana   Tasty
2      3   Peach  Rotten
```

If want add only one column faster is use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
s = df_2.drop_duplicates('Fruit').set_index('Fruit')['Taste']
df_1['Taste'] = df_1['Fruit'].map(s)
print (df_1)
   Index   Fruit   Taste
0      1   Apple   Tasty
1      2  Banana   Tasty
2      3   Peach  Rotten
```

Comment: How to keep only the last match instead of first match?

Comment: @BarathVutukuri - change `.drop_duplicates('Fruit')` to `.drop_duplicates('Fruit', keep='last')`

Comment: what if the fruit does not contain any repeated values? for me it returns NaN after a certain matches.

Comment: best! you saved me!